# Bazel tab auto complete in zsh not working

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, bazel, oh-my-zsh

I use oh-my-zsh and I have a bazel project. I want tab complete. So that I can do `bazel build //src/<tab>` and get auto complete.

The first thing I tried was following:

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/completion.html. I included the _bazel file under a directory on my $fpath. Then I restarted my terminal and got no tab complete.

Next I tried using an oh-my-zsh plugin. https://github.com/jackwish/bazel. I cloned the plugin into the correct location, added bazel to my zshrc plugins and did `source ~/.zshrc`
Still no tab completion.

I installed bazel using brew. I have tried `brew uninstall bazel` and reinstalling it. No luck...

```
$ echo $fpath
... /Users/<username>/.oh-my-zsh/completions ...
$ ls /Users/<username>/.oh-my-zsh/completions
_bazel
```

I want to press tab and get a list of options and be able to tab through them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-initialize the completion. The completion system in ZSH collects completion file in `fpath` and record them in a `.zcompdump` file as an index for existing completions. After a new completion file is added, you need to redo the process.

#### Solution

1. Put the following content into your `.zshrc`.

   ```sh
   # add the _bazel into path
   fpath+=(/path/to/_bazel)
   ```
2. Re-collect completions and generate `.zcompdump`. Run the following command in a **new** interactive ZSH shell.

   ```sh
   rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit
   ```

I remember oh-my-zsh doesn't do the `compinit` for you. You may need to add the `compinit` into your `.zshrc`.

Check the [optimization here to run `compinit` once a day](https://gist.github.com/ctechols/ca1035271ad134841284).

#### Extended Reading

- [Command completion from archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Command_completion)

Answer (score 0):

I had to install zsh-completions (via brew) and follow the instructions after the install to get completions to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct. But here is a quick approach to do it:

```
# First download the _bazel file
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bazelbuild/bazel/master/scripts/zsh_completion/_bazel -o _bazel
# Second move it to completions directory
$ cp _bazel  ~/.oh-my-zsh/completions/
```

`~/.oh-my-zsh/completions/` is already in the $fpath directory. You can check by running `echo $fpath`